# How to access nodejs server with https requests in mvc core web app?

Tags: node.js, express, https, socket.io, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working on a socket.io based chat application which has different client i.e. android, ios and web.
Chat is working correctly in android and iOS apps.

Nodejs server is used as a backend for socket.js communication. Web part is implemented in asp.net mvc core 3.1. I have created self signed certificates by openssl to access nodejs server over https. I have used folowing code

```
varhttp = require('http');  
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
const httpsPort = 1234;  
var https = require('https');  
var fs = require('fs');  
var options = {  
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem', 'utf8'),  
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt', 'utf8')  
};  

var secureServer = https.createServer(options, app).listen(httpsPort, () => {  
    console.log("listening at port " + httpsPort);  
});
```

But the nodejs server is not connecting and different errors are shown

socket.io.js:14 GET https://x.xxx.xx.xx:8083/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NRU7hkg net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

or

certificate is not valid in chrome with following msg

```
This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.
```

How to properly configure nodejs server over https to communicate with client which is a mvc core 3.1 web application without browser security issues/server not found issue ?

Comment: Use trusted certificates, or add your certificates to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared http as variable
Try doing this in first line

var http =  require('http');